# What happened first? The law that authorized the Cuban government to nationalize US firms or Eisenhower's Cuban sugar quota?

Tags: united-states, cuba, eisenhower

I'm asking these because both things happened the same day (6 July 1960) and the sources contradict each other about what happened first. Some Cuban sources says that Castro passed the law because of the US's sugar quota, but other says it was backwards.

Can someone tell me what really happened first?

Comment: Hello and welcome to History:SE!  In order for the members here to help, you will need to provide the sources you are referencing which have conflicting information.  Please take the Site [tour] and visit the [help] and especially review the topic [ask].  This will inform you of how best to use this site to get good answers.

Comment: I found this Eisenhower proclamation about quota naming reasons forbits introduction. It doesn't mention nationalization

Comment: https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/documents/statement-the-president-upon-signing-bill-and-proclamation-relating-the-cuban-sugar-quota

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about your chronology. [Wayne Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayne_Smith_(diplomat)), an American diplomat posted in Cuba, wrote in his book *The Closest of Enemies*:

> Blow followed blow. On June 7, 1960, Esso, Texaco, and the British oil company Shell, refused to refine Soviet crude oil imported by the Cuban government. Cuba responded on June 28 by nationalizing all three foreign refineries. The U.S. Congress, in turn, on July 3 authorized the termination of Cuba's sugar quota, and on July 6 President Eisenhower, acting on that authorization, announced that the U.S. would not buy the 700,000 tons of Cuban sugar remaining in the 1960 quota. Cuba retaliated by nationalizing all U.S.-owned industrial and agrarian enterprises on August 6 and all U.S.-owned banks on September 17.